# Per replace newlines not working as expected

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to replace newlines in a file `tmp` using Perl, but getting unexpected behavior as shown below.

```
user$ cat tmp
aa
bb
cc


user$ perl -p -e 's/\n/==/g' tmp
aa==bb==cc==

user$ perl -p -e 's/\nbb/==/g' tmp
aa
bb
cc
```

Why is the output not

```
aa==
cc
```

instead?

Comment: try `perl -pe -0777`

Comment: @AvinashRaj `perl -p -e -0777 's/\nbb/==/g' tmp`
Can't open s/\nbb/==/g: No such file or directory.

Comment: `perl -0777 -p -e ...`

Comment: sorry, your regex must be next to `-e`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here that -p flag loops your code like:

```
LINE:
    while (<>) {
    ...     # your program goes here
    } continue {
    print or die "-p destination: $!\n";
    }
```

So your regexp runs for each line. Just use `-0777` option to read the entire file as one line:

```
perl -p -0777 -e 's/\nbb/==/g' tmp
```